# Why does my function work only some of the time?

Tags: python

Given two strings, return True if either of the strings appears at the very end of the other string, ignoring upper/lower case differences (in other words, the computation should not be "case sensitive"). Note: s.lower() returns the lowercase version of a string.

```
def end_other(a, b):
  small = min(a, b)
  big = max(a, b)
  bigcut = big[-len(small):]
  if small.lower() == bigcut.lower():
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

It works for `end_other('AbC', 'HiaBc')` but not `end_other('Hiabc', 'abc')`

Comment: I suspect `min(a, b)` and `max(a, b)` do not do what you want.

Comment: Try  min/max with key function i.e. `min(a, b, key = len)` and `max(a, b, key = len)`

Answer (score 2):

`min(a, b)` returns the string that is "lexicographically smaller", i.e., that comes first in the dictionary. You can instead use `min(a, b, key=len)` to correctly get the shorter string, or perhaps the following:

```py
def end_other(a, b):
    if len(a) > len(b): # make sure a is shorter
        a, b = b, a
    return b.lower().endswith(a.lower())

print(end_other('AbC', 'HiaBc')) # True
print(end_other('Hiabc', 'abc')) # True
print(end_other('a', 'b')) # False
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you use min() and max() will not place the shorter and longer strings in small and big because these functions are not comparing string sizes but string content.

You could let zip() handle the difference in length for you by giving it the characters in reversed order:

```
def end_other(a, b):
    return all(a.lower()==b.lower() for a,b in zip(a[::-1],b[::-1]))

print(end_other('AbC', 'HiaBc')) # True
print(end_other('Hiabc', 'abc')) # True
print(end_other('ABCDEF', 'abc')) # False
```

You could also compute the shortest length and apply it to both strings in the comparison:

```
def end_other(a, b):
    s = min(len(a),len(b))
    return a[-s:].lower() == b[-s:].lower()
```

Or use endswith (which almost reads like english):

```
def end_other(a, b):
    return a.lower().endswith(b.lower()) or b.lower().endswith(a.lower())
```

Comment: The second way fails for example `end_other('', 'b')`.

Comment: Indeed, b[0:] returns the whole string ('b') so the comparison would need to be more complex (`a[::-1][:s].lower() == b[::-1][:s].lower()`).  I guess you could use the 2nd solution if your requirement is to consider empty strings as non-eligible suffixes.

Comment: Yeah that works. I like your zip idea. Could also use map with two iterables: `return all(map(operator.eq, a.lower()[::-1], b.lower()[::-1]))`

Comment: There are so many ways to do this.  here's another idea: `str.endswith(*sorted(map(str.lower,(a,b)),key=len)[::-1])`

Comment: Yeah I had done that as well, except went one step further with `def end_other(*a):` so I didn't have to unpack and repack the args.

Answer (score 0):

```
def end_other(a, b):
  if (a.lower()).endswith(b.lower()):
    return True
  elif (b.lower()).endswith(a.lower()):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Sharing my solution here!